# Print list of numbers into HTML body

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to show the multiplication result list in HTML. In the console, I can see the list of numbers but that one I can not print in HTML. Any help, please?

HTML

```
<p id="secondP"></p>
<p id="x"></p>
```

js

```
function showData() {
    var theSelect = demoForm.part;
    var secondP = document.getElementById('secondP');
    secondP.innerHTML = ('Its Standerd Pack is: ' + theSelect[theSelect.selectedIndex].value);
    
    var num = theSelect[theSelect.selectedIndex].value

    for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      result = i * num;

      console.log(result);
      document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = result;
    }
}
```

Comment: document.getElementById("x").innerHTML += result;

Comment: It works, but in HTML result comes like 00000246810 for multiplication of 2 @Naren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the code `document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = result;`, it changed the value of the element, *even if* it already has a value. If you want to add a value to an element, use `document.getElementById("x").innerHTML += result;` this will add the value to your element, for example, if the element's value is `hello`, and you use `document.getElementById("x").innerHTML +=' world';`, the element's value will become `hello world` instead of  `world`.